# Router in half bridge floods arp cache

Tags: slackware, adsl, arptables

I've set up a Slackware (14.0) box as a gateway for my adsl connection. I have a modem set up in half bridge mode between the NIC and the phone line, and the interface takes up the dynamically assigned public ip via DHCP. I've found the for every single ip i need to connect to gets it's own arp cache entry, so while bittorrenting the cache easily collects over 1000 entries. The following is my (truncated) routing table:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         121.99.51.213   0.0.0.0         UG    203    0        0 eth1
121.99.51.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     203    0        0 eth1
```

My intuition tells me if i remove the second entry it will stop spamming arp requests (but I of course may be totally mistaken). I've been able to remove it, but it seems the kernel automagically adds a new route based on the ip and netmask of the interface. Is there any way to remove the route permanently? Or perhaps disable arp caching on that one interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting my default route to the ip address of the modem itself fixed the issue.